# How can I check if it is between 2pm and 1am new york time?

Tags: java

I need to check if the time in new york time zone is between 2pm and 1 am but i am not sure how to select the timezone or what to do next

```
  String string1 = "14:00:00";
    Date time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(string1);
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTime(time1);

    String string2 = "01:00:00";
    Date time2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(string2);
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.setTime(time2);
    calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Comment: What is your input? Are you interested in the *current* time? What does 14:11 have to do with it?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes i want to get the current time of new york. if it is between that range i want to perform some task

Comment: @code578841441 So if the current time is 3pm do you want to execute your task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interested in whether the *current* time is "after or equal to 2pm, or before 1am" then don't need to use string parsing at all. You could use:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(zone);
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if (hour < 1 || hour >= 14) {
    ...
}
```

That's assuming you *do* want it to match 3pm, but you *don't* want it to match 8am, for example. That's "between 2pm and 1am" in my view, as per your title.

If you're using Java 8, I'd suggest using `LocalTime` instead, via `ZonedDateTime`:

```
private static final LocalTime EARLY_CUTOFF = LocalTime.of(1, 0);
private static final LocalTime LATE_CUTOFF = LocalTime.of(14, 0);

ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
LocalTime time = ZonedDateTime.now(zone).toLocalTime();
if (time.compareTo(EARLY_CUTOFF) < 0 && time.compareTo(LATE_CUTOFF) >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar calNewYork = Calendar.getInstance();   
calNewYork.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
int curr_hour = calNewYork.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

System.out.println(curr_hour < 1 || curr_hour >= 14);
```

Comment: That will be from 2am to 13:59:59.999pm. I believe the OP wants it from 2pm until 00:59:59.999am.

Comment: @JonSkeet Whatever, Jon Skeet talked to me :) I corrected it though, as you pointed out this is excluding the bounding hours.

Comment: How can `curr_hour` be both less than 1 *and* more than 14? (I'm personally treating the end as exclusive and the start as inclusive... that's a common approach.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Makes sense, i copied the condition over from you answer. What is the benefit of using `LocalTime`?

Comment: `LocalTime` makes it clearer that you *only* care about the time of day. In general, the new time API is better. I've just noticed a bug in my current answer with `LocalTime` though...